# Display firestore document data in a datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display data from my Firestore in a data grid. I can return all rows if I do it in a ListView, but I really need this to be in a datagrid. I am also able to return one row using the code below. I have tried using a list collection and an observable collection, both seem to return one row aswell.

```
async void GetFurtherWorksApp()
    {

        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"cloudfire.json";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);

        database = FirestoreDb.Create("engineer-app");

        Query DOC = database.Collection("further_works");
        QuerySnapshot snap = await DOC.GetSnapshotAsync();



        foreach (DocumentSnapshot docsnap in snap.Documents)
        {
            FurtherWorks job = docsnap.ConvertTo<FurtherWorks>();


            //FurtherWorksList.Items.Add( new { docsnap.Id, job.company, job.cost, job.jobnumber, job.jobstatus, job.partsreq, job.timespent, job.timesreq });

            //FurtherWorksList.Items.Add(new { Col1 = docsnap.Id, Col2 = job.company, Col3 = job.cost, Col4 = job.jobstatus, Col5 = job.partsreq, Col6 = job.timespent, Col7 = job.timereq });

            //FurtherWorksList.Columns.Add(  Col1 = docsnap.Id, Col2 = job.company, Col3 = job.cost, Col4 = job.jobstatus, Col5 = job.partsreq, Col6 = job.timespent, Col7 = job.timereq );

            ObservableCollection<FurtherWorks> items = new ObservableCollection<FurtherWorks>();
            items.Add(new FurtherWorks { jobnumber = job.jobnumber, company = job.company, cost = job.cost });
            FurtherWorksList.ItemsSource = items;


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to save in collection first move outside of forereach loop as well as ItemSource like this.

```
ObservableCollection<FurtherWorks> items = new ObservableCollection<FurtherWorks>();
        foreach (DocumentSnapshot docsnap in snap.Documents)
        {
            FurtherWorks job = docsnap.ConvertTo<FurtherWorks>();

            items.Add(new FurtherWorks { jobnumber = job.jobnumber, company = job.company, cost = job.cost });

        }
        FurtherWorksList.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, cheers. It makes sense now I see it.